# Extended Posix Regular Expression - Negation of multiple strings using "^"

Tags: regex, posix, regex-negation

I have an old application which uses Extended POSIX regular expression for evaluating a return code in order to take some decisions.

Examples of Return Codes:

```
RETCODE = 0 SUCCESS
RETCODE = 3007 ERR3007
RETCODE = 3001 ERR3001
RETCODE = 13007 ERR13007
RETCODE = 3 ERR3
RETCODE = 1 ERR1
```

I wrote a regular expression for considering SUCCESS when return code is 0 OR 3007:  ".*RETCODE = (0|3007).*"

Now I need another regular expression for considering FAILURE when return code is anything else. it means, when return code is neither 0 NOR 3007.

NOTE 1: My application considers only "^" as the negation character.

NOTE 2: I test the expression using command "egrep"

Could you please help me with this situation?

Thanks in Advance.

Ivan.

Comment: Would you tell us why do you need two regular expressions? since `RETCODE = ((0|3007)|([0-9]+))[ ]` matches both types of returns and stores success codes within second capturing groups and the failures within third.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX extended regular expressions do not support negative lookahead assertions.  However, the complement of a regular language is itself regular again, so there is a regular expression you can write for this, it is just really unwieldy, even if you do not aim for a precise negation of the match:

```
RETCODE = ([124-9][0-9]*|3|30|3[1-9][0-9]*|30[1-9][0-9]*|300|300[01-689][0-9]*|3007[0-9]+)[ ]
```

Comment: A character class should include `0`. Currently it doesn't allow `3000`.

Comment: Thanks. A few other corner cases where missing, too.